# JPA Query : how to use select * from my_table where created_at > now() - INTERVAL '3 months'?

Tags: java, jpa

How do I add a `where` clause with a condition `created_at > now() - INTERVAL '3 months'`?

JPA Entity Column:

```
@Column(name = "created_at")
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named queries.

Annotate your entity class with:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Entity.findByCreatedDateGreaterThan", query = "FROM Entity e WHERE u.createdDate > :date")
```

To use this named query:

```
public List<Entity> getEntityByCreatedDateGreaterThan() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -90);
    Query namedQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Entity.findByCreatedDateGreaterThan");
    namedQuery.setParameter("date", calendar.getTime());
    return namedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using Calendar, the java 8 LocalDateTime API is recommended.

Comment: Use LocalDateTime like this(Beaware about the timezone) `Date pastDate = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(90).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());`